# Azure Slot Swapping didn't work as expected

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

We are using Azure - slot deployment in Production environment.
- We are using App services 
- 2 slots (Staging and default Production Slot)

We deployed code on Slot and after testing it we started doing a swap from Azure but the site on production stopped and the error - "Internal server error" was displayed on the page.

We restarted App service but still same error was displayed! We then changed CustomError to Off mode and after that site was up (as app pool was recycled)

Can anyone help me with this, as slot deployment was not successful as site was down because of slot swapping?

Comment: Log errors and check logs?

Comment: Can you please elaborate ? We cannot test the same on Production and collect logs .. If anyone faced this issue that why app pool was not recycled when swapping was performed.